# How to make strokes appear 3D in the After Effects 3D (Cinema 4D) Mode?

Tags: after-effects, animation, cinema4d

I am currently animating a rotating 3D globe, built out of stroked paths. However this is causing a problem - the strokes are rendered on a 2d plane, so as they near parallel with the perspective, they disappear.

Is there a way to render strokes so that they behave as though they were 3d (interacting with perspective and rotation as a cylindrical tube would)?

[image: The line closest to the camera is thinnest]

Thanks a lot